# Struts2 upgrade error

Tags: struts2

I just upgraded from `Struts 2.0.6` with `Spring 2.0` to `Struts 2.2.3`. I am getting the following error on application startup. I have added the following jars. Please let me know if i missed something. In windows machine, my own validation methods are ignored and xworks validation gets control and throws a validation error. This does not happen in linux machine.

```
 struts2-core-2.2.3
 struts2-json-plugin-2.2.3
 struts2-spring-plugin-2.2.3
 xwork-core-2.2.3
 commons-fileupload-1.2.2
 commons-collections-3.2
```

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFileParser.parseValidatorDefinitions(DefaultValidatorFileParser.java:105)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.retrieveValidatorConfiguration(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:184)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.parseValidators(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:173)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.<init>(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:419)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:581)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:530)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:581)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:530)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:485)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.injectInternalBeans(ObjectFactory.java:127)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:162)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:180)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:59)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:987)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:806)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:819)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:842)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:449)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    [2011-05-19 22:37:43,354] com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder ERROR (CommonsLogger.java:error:27):
    Actual exception
    Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - interceptor - jar:file:/home/mr/Apps/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/slmp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.3.jar!/struts-default.xml:149:127
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:59)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:987)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:806)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:819)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:842)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:449)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:485)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.injectInternalBeans(ObjectFactory.java:127)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:162)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:180)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:495)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:581)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:530)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
        ... 56 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
        ... 61 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        ... 63 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:495)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:581)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:530)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
        ... 68 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:440)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
        ... 73 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:419)
        ... 74 more
    Caused by: Document is invalid: no grammar found. - file:///home/mr/Apps/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/bin/validators.xml:1:12
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFileParser.parseValidatorDefinitions(DefaultValidatorFileParser.java:105)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.retrieveValidatorConfiguration(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:184)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.parseValidators(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:173)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.<init>(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:44)
        ... 79 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
```

Comment: See **[Troubleshooting guide migrating from Struts 2.0.x to 2.1.x](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Now OpenSymphony has seen it's final days. All xml have to change the dtd to struts.apache.org.

xworks related DTD's have been uploaded on struts site "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/"

E.g. To fix your validation xml files.

**Old way of validation DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
        "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

**Replace with New validation DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

Try and see if above option helps.